# Date range/query problem

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 fields:

- id
- datestart
- dateend

I need to query this to find out if a pair of dates from a form are conflicting i.e

table entry  1, 2010-12-01, 2010-12-09

from the form  2010-12-08, 2010-12-15    (edited, typo)

```
select id 
  from date_table  
 where '2010-12-02' between datestart and dateend
```

That returns me the `id` that I want, but what I would like to do is to take the date range from the form and do a query similar to what I have got that will take both form dates `2010-12-08, 20-12-15` and query the db to ensure that there is no conflicting date ranges in the table.

Am sat scratching my head with the problem...

TIA

Comment: `20-12-15` - is it really date? or just mistake?

Comment: also define `conflicting` please

Comment: not entirely inside or even partial? usually a picture can help. on a paper. Draw a timeline with pencil and then try various combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your request correctly you would like a list of all entries in date_table that either overlaps your form_start, your form_end or is entirely contained within the form_start - form_end date range.

So your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT id FROM
date_table
WHERE
(datestart < form_start AND dateend => form_start)
OR
(datestart <= form_end AND dateend > form_end)
OR
(datestart >= form_start  AND dateend <= form_end)
```

Comment: thanks for that, it got me thinking about the problem and sort of partially resolved it myself... (was full resolved until my boss threw me a curve ball)..  Overlap is allowed, as the fitting crew finishes jobs in the morning and can be scheduled to start another in the afternoon !!!


`SELECT
  av_bookedid,
  av_datestart,
  av_dateend
FROM date_table
WHERE ('form_start' BETWEEN datestart
         AND dateend)
     OR ('form_end'BETWEEN datestart
         AND dateend);`

Comment: I don't know if this applies to your scenario, but you'd still miss those form dates overlapping entire date spans in the date_table.

You could catch those by adding an OR (form_start < datestart AND dateend < form_end)

Comment: Thats the bit I need !!!   You are a GOD  !!!!!

crazy that something so simple can feel so far away ...

Thank you so much my friend

Answer (score -1):

```
select id from date_table where '2010-12-02' between datestart and dateend;
```

I am not aware of the scope of your program. But, it seems like you're saying: select id from table where this date "2010-12-02" is in between 2 variables. I think you want to select where datestart is between the 2 variables.

Forgive me & correct me if I am wrong? You probably want something like this:

```
SELECT id FROM date_table WHERE datestart = datestart AND dateend = dateend;
```

if that's the case you probably just want a count:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM date_table WHERE datestart = datestart AND dateend = dateend;
```

Good luck!

Comment: In plain english what am needing is to ensure that the date range from the form `form_start` to `form_end` does not overlap with the date ranges in the table `datestart` to `dateend`

Maybe some extra info would help, am doing this for my boss (I'm a welder !) and we use a number of fitting crews to install steelwork job, we want to be able to get a list `id` of crews that are available...


Maybe that will help a bit ?

Comment: `select id from date_table where '2010-12-02' between datestart and dateend;`

should read something like (in english)

`SELECT id FROM date_table WHERE RANGE form_date_start TO form_date_end IN range datestart TO dateend`

So that "should" give me a list of `id` that is busy on a job at sometime in the date range...